# Checking Object Notation if user sets to function

Tags: javascript, function, object

How do you check if the object notation that is being ran is the default coding or if they added `function` to it?

EX:

```
var object ={
      easy:function() {
       alert('Hello');
     } 
    };
```

`object.easy();`

Now how do I check if it is that or if it is this instantiation

```
 object.easy(function() {
   alert('GoodBye');
 }
```

Comment: You want to check if `easy` is being called with or without an argument?

Comment: basically see I wasn't sure if a function was considered an argument in that sense.

Comment: The question is unclear actually, `default coding`, `it is this instantiation`... don't make much sense.

Comment: Sure, you can pass a function as an argument to another function, happens all the time in JavaScript. For example, this sort of thing is common with jQuery: `$(x).click(function() { ... })`.

Comment: @loxxy sorry I wrote this fast :)

Comment: @muistooshort how do I check against the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Any function in JavaScript can be called with any number of arguments regardless of how many arguments you specify when you say `function(...) { ... }`. If you want to look at the arguments, you can use the [`arguments` pseudo-array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments):

> An `Array`-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

And if you want to know if you've been handed a function or not, you can use the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

> The `typeof` operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

So you can see if you've been passed a function with something like this:

```
var object = {
    easy: function() {
        if(arguments.length > 0
        && typeof arguments[0] === 'function')
            console.log('Yup, we have been passed a function');
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/c4zTZ/

Comment: Hey Thanks Mu Is Too Short I will test this out now!